# Python / pytesseract: Extract groups of numbers from image

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm trying to use the pytesseract module to extract some numbers from an image:

[image]

The result I get is:

> NON 1,1 mn 144 701 319 145
>
> ENS 432 755 205 000 227 755
>
> SHB 234 050 18 867 215 183

How can remove the blank spaces in an automatic fashion (I have hundreds of these images) to get the wanted output:

> NON 1,1 mn 144701 319145
>
> ENS 432755 205000 227755
>
> SHB 234050 18867 215183

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Answer (score 0):

May be my answer got delayed. For the exact scenario i had tried with **easyocr** instead of pytesseract. Easyocr also uses tesseract engine for OCR.The code is,

```
import easyocr


def format_string(texts, no_of_columns):
    total_line = []
    line_text = []
    for index in range(len(texts)):
        line_text.append(texts[index])
        if (index + 1) % no_of_columns == 0:
            string_data = " ".join(line_text)
            total_line.append(string_data)
            line_text = []
    return total_line


IMAGE_PATH = 'P.png'
reader = easyocr.Reader(['en'])
result = reader.readtext(IMAGE_PATH)
texts = [detection[1].replace(' ', '') for detection in result if detection[2] > 0.5]
output = format_string(texts, 4)
```

The format_string() method will join individual strings in ocr list with respect to column number in image. Here the number of columns is 4, so I pass argument as 4.
The output is,

```
['NON 1,1mn 744701 319145', 'ENS 432755 205000 227755', 'SHB 234050 18867 215183']
```

Might be this will useful for you. Happy coding :)